# cron job schedule not running as expected

Tags: cron

I tried scheduling a cron job to run every 25 minutes with the below string:
"*/25 * * * * echo "test".

But if we see the scheduled output:
01:00,01:25,01:50,02:00,02:25 (it is executing for every starting hour as well).

I am looking for a cron string that executes the job on the following schedule: 01:00,01:25,01:50, 02:15,02:40

Can anyone please help me to get the right schedule string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to add in script the logic to check if `(hour*60+minutes)%25` give you zero and only then exec the command(s). And schedule the script to run every 5 minutes.

Another way is to set explicitly the files like:

```
0,25,50 0,5,10,15,20 * * * /path/to/executable
15,40 1,6,11,16,21 * * * /path/to/executable
5,30,55 2,7,12,17,22 * * * /path/to/executable
20,45 3,8,13,18,23 * * * /path/to/executable
10,35 4,9,14,19 * * * /path/to/executable
```

But in any way you will have execution in 23:45 and the next in 0:00 which will broke the rule. If you want to follow it between days will become quite complex (you need to take in consideration also leap years).

Comment: Thanks Romeo for the reply, it seems too complex to put explicit timings. Better option will be (hour*60+minutes)%25.

Comment: @pluto, if you like my answer feel free to accept it (tick on the left of the answer text)